# Screen won't switch off, but stays black instead

Tags: screen, screensaver

I want my screen to switch off after some time. I have set this in the settings, but after the specified time, the screen goes black but does not switch off. I tried to google how to solve this issue but without success. How do I solve this?

I am using Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: Can you try the terminal command `xset dpms force off`? If your monitor is capable of that, this should turn it off according to the [DPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling) standard until you move the mouse or press any button again.

Comment: Yes, this does indeed switch the screen off. The problem is probably in that the screen goes black instead of switching off rather that it is not able to.

Comment: You can set an inactivity timeout after which the screen goes off with that command, like `xset dpms 0 0 600` would turn it off after 10 minutes (600s) of inactivity. (The other two zeroes are for standby and suspend.) Not sure at the moment if there is a better GUI way to make these settings. You can query the current values with `xset q`.